# Which kingdoms were using WWI weapons at the time of the second world war?

Tags: world-war-two, military, world-war-one, weapons

Which kingdoms, little dictatorships and all sorts of fiefdom had World War 1 armor (and nothing more modern) at the time of the second war? I bet there was a lot because after the First World War all that equipment was sold off to little kingdom for which this firepower was real upgrade. In particular tanks and similar armored vehicles.

Wikipedia says only this:
The volume of the arms trade greatly increased during the 20th century, and it began to be used as a political tool, especially during the Cold War where the United States and the USSR supplied weapons to their proxies across the world, particularly third world countries (see Nixon Doctrine).[9]https://origins.osu.edu/article/merchants-death-international-traffic-arms/page/0/1 says something about sales to China and Spain.

Comment: Simplified title because  it took me three tries to parse it.  I'm still confused as to whether you're asking for WWI _weapons_ or WWI armor.

Comment: Thank you for your question; could you give us an overview of the [research you have done so far](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599) and explain what you find to be unclear or missing? Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) may be helpful.

Comment: Many naval vessels used in WW2 were launched before/during WW1.

Comment: As but one interesting ship, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chilean_battleship_Almirante_Latorre was ordered by Chile in 1911 from a UK shipyard, 'bought' by the UK for use in WW1, returned to Chile in 1920 , and used by Chile during WW2 for neutrality patrols (after, perhaps, turning down offers from both the Soviets and the Americans to buy it).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renault_FT#Operators   The old Renault FT was still kicking on WW2, e.g., Yugoslavia, Romania. A little more if you count training units, even Canada, Brazil, Switzerland. It makes sense as an anti-partisan unit. How would you counter it with no heavy weapons?

Comment: Kingdoms or countries?

Answer (score 4):

More than you can imagine, and not only minor kingdoms.

The main actors of WWII where still using WWI equipment, specially at the beginning.

From the navy standpoint, many main unit where still from WWI (all [Queen Elizabeth-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Elizabeth-class_battleship) and [Revenge-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revenge-class_battleship), for example, for UK) for all the participant.
From infantry, lot of equipment was from WWI, here few examples:

[Soviet Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Soviet_Union_military_equipment_of_World_War_II):

- [Mosin Nagant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosin%E2%80%93Nagant#World_War_II) was the standard rifle

[French Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_World_War_II_weapons_of_France):

- Handguns ([Star Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Model_14), [MAS 1873 Revolver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAS_1873_revolver), and more)
- Rifles ([M1917 Enfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebel_Model_1886_rifle), and more)
- Machine gun ([Hotchkiss Mle 1914](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotchkiss_Mle_1914_machine_gun))

[German Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_German_military_equipment_of_World_War_II):

- Machine Guns ([MG 08](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MG_08))
- Artillery ([21 cm Mörser 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/21_cm_M%C3%B6rser_16))

[Japan Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Japanese_military_equipment_of_World_War_II):

- Machine Guns ([Type 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_3_heavy_machine_gun))

Here I've put some examples, the space of the answer is too little to put all the weapons from WWI used in WWII and other wars (for examples, Type 3 machine gun was used still in the Vietnam war).

Comment: @Jan Kaiserliche Marine was dismantled at the end of WWI (Germany was allowed ["six pre-dreadnought battleships and was limited to a maximum of six light cruisers ..., twelve destroyers ... and twelve torpedo boats ... and was forbidden submarines"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Versailles#Military_restrictions) ). Two pre-dreadnought battleship took part of WWII - [SMS Schleswig-Holstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_Schleswig-Holstein) and [SMS Schlesien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_Schlesien) (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Kriegsmarine_ships))

Comment: you are right. Schleswig-Holstein in fact opened the war, so she is kind of significant.

Comment: Not surprised- there were biplane early in second world war but armored vehicles were probably all sold off.

Comment: @user2617804 not really - Japan had some armoured vehicles from WWI in service, and France had seven front-line battalions equipedd with [Renault FT-17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renault_FT#World_War_II_and_after)

Comment: HMS Hood was not from WWI ir was launched just after but several others were eg Warspite plus US and Japanaese

Comment: UK artillery included 18 pounders from WWI let alone many heavier ones plus all the rifles of all nations were WWI

Comment: @mmmmmm: you'r right about HMS Hood; it was commissioned in 1916, and ready in 1918. For UK, all the Queen Elizabeth-class (not only Warspite) and Revenge-class ships took part to both wars. Answer updated

Answer (score 3):

Why limit yourself to WW1? The Dutch army went to battle in 1940 with (some) equipment predating the Franco-Prussian war.

- [Dutch equipment WW2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dutch_military_equipment_of_World_War_II)

*added:*

I think the question is mood. Why? Because the age of a weapon is not that important. Look at the time period: 1914-1940 = 26 years.

Many advanced weapons systems in common use today are **much** older:

- The [Boeing B52](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-52_Stratofortress) flew 69 years ago. There is no replacement planned. It will fly almost certainly for another 30-40 years.
- The [ROC Hai Shih submarine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Cutlass_(SS-478)) *(former USS Cutlass)* was launched in 1944, and is still serving.
- The [Lockheed Hercules C 130](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_C-130_Hercules) flew in 1954, and will continue to do that in the foreseeable future. Like the B52, it might clock a century.
- The [M113 APC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M113_armored_personnel_carrier) is in continuous use since 1960, and will do that for many decades to come.
- The [T34](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-34) dates from 1940. Nine countries still use it today.
- The [M2 Browning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M2_Browning) .50 machinegun became operational in 1933. It still is a very current weapon, and will be that probably for another 50 years at least.

If we take those examples, and place them against 1914 you'd go back to well before the Crimean War of 1853. That's not possible or even realistic, of course. Sometimes weapons remain in extended use for many reasons.

Comment: The earliest in that list seems to be a revolver from 1873. The F-P war was 1870-1.

Comment: @TomasBy the list is incomplete and doesn't tell nearly the entire story. The Dutch army on the start of hostilities emptied the army museum of among others front loading field guns and rifles. Most of the more modern stuff that is on the list also was in extremely short supply and ammo for it even harder to come by. Also, often the numbers reflect ordered or planned numbers rather than what was actually available for action.

Comment: @jwenting I know. But what's there should be good enough to get the picture. If the Dutch army had just WW1 equipment, they would have lasted longer. (six days ...)

Comment: @Jos maybe. Or maybe there would just have been more casualties as the Germans would have resorted to more artillery and air strikes rather than ignore things like 1880s era artillery lobbing the occasional shell. I do know my grandfather went up to tanks and stukas on the Grebbe with just his rifle, he was one of the less than 10% to survive that episode.

Comment: @jwenting We're both Dutch, and well versed in history. Rotterdam may - doubtful - have been an accident, but they sure as hell would have bombed anything possible if Winkelman hadn't surrenderd.

Comment: @Jos yeah, from my investigations I came to understand that the cancelation message for the Rotterdam strike wasn't received in time by the bomber bases and that the bombers were either operating under radio silence or for some other reason didn't receive the recall. It's one of those things that just happen in war, like the US bombing of Enschede when a bomb group got lost and thought they were over Muenster.

Comment: @jwenting front loading field guns? as in Napoleonic wars? I somehow find that a little bit difficult to believe without sources.

Comment: @TomasBy that's what we were taught in history class in the 1970s, by people who were adults during WW2. They basically took whatever they could get out of the museums apparently.

Comment: @TomasBy No, that's a hoax. Yes, antediluvian artillery was pulled from museums. But not front loading artillery. That was even for the government too much.

Comment: AK-47 and MG42/MG3 were also developed quite some time ago

Answer (score 0):

The french 75mm field gun (Canon de 75 modèle 1897, which came out in WWI) and was still available in large numbers in 1940 ?

Which was used by France, Poland, Great Britain and the US 1940.

In the case of the US, the carriage was changed into a split trail design.